# how do you set background image in a column of col-lg-12 using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can you set the background image in a column of `col-lg-12` using Bootstrap?

Comment: Please try to add more information to your post

Comment: I tried setting a background img inside a column, the img doesn't display unless I use src=
if I tried using inputting in LESS this code = background - image: url(../img/bg.jpg) 
the image still doesn't display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, like on any other element. Assuming your `col-lg-12` is on a `<div>`, you can add another class/style to add a background, e.g.

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="background-image: url('some.png')">
  Your content goes here
</div>
```

You can find a class example on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-image